# PostgreSQL импорт из файла

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, symfony2, doctrine

Какой самый быстрый способ импортировать файл CSV в базу данных кроме COPY. Данных очень много, около 125 млн записей.

Загружаются они по крону раз в день. Парсить и заливать по одной строке не айс. Дифф никак не получить, только файл целиком со всеми записями. 
Все это на Symfony, если как то поможет или есть встроенные инструменты.

Comment: построчно читать из файла csv , если разделитель ; то элементарно по столбцам разделить вот пример https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33714044/fopen-php-mysql-import-empty-row-in-sql

Comment: Самый быстрый способ - это на основе csv файла сделать sql с батчингом строк. И через консоль импортировать этот sql файл.

Comment: Обратите внимание на такой инструмент, например . https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts/csvsql.html

Если подойдет, то можете создать консольную команду, которая будет работать с данным инструментом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Единственный быстрый способ загрузить такое кол-во записей в базу, это использовать команду COPY

```
COPY table(column1, column2) FROM 'list_data.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Для 125 млн записей импорт занимает около минуты. эта команда требует прав root. Для запуска без прав администратора есть мета команда \copy

```
\copy table(column1, column2) FROM '/path/to/csv/data.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV
```